# Passing down function from parent to child through React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to pass down the functions `setDir` and `handleSort()` down from `SearchAppointments` (parent) to `Hooks`(child), but I keep getting errors saying that they are not functions.

I tried to debug it by looking the `typeof` `handleSort` in the `useEffect`hook of the child component, though it console.logged two statements: 1) underfined 2) function. Not sure what is wrong.

```
const SearchAppointments = React.memo(() => {
  const [orderDir, setDir] = useState("");

  const handleSort = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    setDir(value);
    let order;
    let filterData = data;
    if (orderDir === 'asc') {
      order = 1;
    } else {
      order = -1;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Hooks handleSort={handleSort} setDir={setDir} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
});
```

```
const Hooks = React.memo(({ handleSort, setDir }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(typeof handleSort);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setDir("success")}>
          Set Dir
        </button>
        <button type="button" value='asc' onClick={handleSort}>
          Handle Sort (Asc)
        </button>
        <button type="button" value='dsc' onClick={handleSort}>
          Handle Sort (Dsc)
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: is it not working? it seems all fine

Comment: `react.memo` needs to take a second argument. have you tried it without memo?

Comment: All seems to work as expected [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-morning-ij5zs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark), even with the `memo` HOC. Have you tried without the `memo` HOC in your code? You should try reducing your code's complexity when debugging. `memo` is usually also used when rerendering is an issue, like performance. Don't prematurely try to optimize your code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I deleted ```memo``` and it is working now. But can you tell me what may have been the problem using ```memo``` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and use `memo` like this:

```
const comparator = (previous, next) => {
    if (something) {
       return true
    }
    return false
}
```

```
const Hooks = React.memo(({ handleSort, setDir }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(typeof handleSort);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setDir("success")}>
          Set Dir
        </button>
        <button type="button" value='asc' onClick={handleSort}>
          Handle Sort (Asc)
        </button>
        <button type="button" value='dsc' onClick={handleSort}>
          Handle Sort (Dsc)
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}, comparator);
```

define a function and pass that as the second argument. `memo` function (I've called it `comparator`, then returns `true` or `false` depending on when you want the component to update. think of it as the new `shouldComponentUpdate` in the lifecycle methods. but use with care as your application might not update if you use carelessly